# Delphi 2010 weird OpenSSL issue

Tags: delphi, openssl

So i was working on a application that uses the indy10 openssl libraries. There was no problem... Everything worked correctly. I could ship the exe without any dll files(Witch i am required to do)... Did a fresh windows install, updated to the latest version of windows 7, installed delphi xe5(Exact same way i did before the fresh install) Then boom!! Could not load openssl libraries... Now for some reason i need to ship the dll files with the exe. I may not ship anything but the exe. Why did this happen? What exactly happened? I also tried the Openssl installer and that did not work either. Can anyone at least explain to me why this happened? Everything is EXACTLY the same from when i left of. Please help me out.

Comment: If you dont ship the OpenSSL DLLs, they have to be installed on the target system separately. The DLLs are not included in a fresh Windows install.

Comment: What really? I used the application with that functionality on a system that does not have them installed. Maybe i was just mistaken. Thank you.

Comment: Install OpenSSL.  You may be shipping just the exe, but without an installer that installs OpenSSL your clients will also need to manually install OpenSSL themselves.  If it was working for you before and it's working for your clients it's because, at some point in the past, OpenSSL was installed on those systems.

Comment: Thank you guys so much. Its quite obvious now that i think about it. The problem was i phoned the client and he told me he has never installed openssl before. maybe it was a application that he has on his computer.

Comment: Even more, you'll need to be sure the version of OpenSSL installed is compatible with the version of Indy you're using. Surely you can't expect your clients to know this.

Comment: Is there any free alternatives i can use that does not require shipping with dll files?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is that you can't ship more than one file. That's what installers are for. You need an installer. For example, Inno Setup.

Comment: The client does not want any installer. He just wants the user to download the exe and run it. I also don't know why he is against a installer but you gotta give the clients what they want hey.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Indy components better to use native THTTPClient from System.Net.HttpClient unit. It works with SSL and https transparently on all platforms (Android, iOS, Mac) without DLLS and problems, and more stable than Indy.

Comment: Thank you. But i export the dll's from the application to system32 now, if the system does not allow it i export it next to the application itself.

Next time ill be sure to go check your suggestion out.